# On Android 10 and above, I cannot make outgoing calls in the background and when the screen is locked

Tags: android, flutter

I am running my Flutter App on a Xiaomi 9c model phone with Android version 10. My app only initiates the outgoing call when it switches to the foreground, it does not initiate the call in the background. I wrote a function that can perform the service and call in the foreground. These listen to firebase transactions and initiate the call if a variable is true. It does not initiate the outgoing call when the screen is locked and in the background. My mainacitivty structure, foreground service structure and androidmanifest file are as follows. (I get the foreground notification, there is no problem with that) Phones I tested(Xiaomi Android 10, Samsung Android 12)

ForeGroundService

```
class ExampleService : Service() {
    private val notificationId = 1
    private var serviceRunning = false
    private lateinit var builder: NotificationCompat.Builder
    private lateinit var channel: NotificationChannel
    private lateinit var manager: NotificationManager
    private lateinit var telephonyManager: TelephonyManager
    private val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    private var callStartTime: Long = 0
    private var callEndTime: Long = 0
    
    private var callRegisterDocumentId: String? = null

    private var username: String = "" 

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        createNotificationChannel()
        startCallStateListener()
        serviceRunning = true
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
         this.username = intent?.getStringExtra("username") ?: ""

        startForeground(notificationId, builder.build())
        serviceRunning = true
        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        serviceRunning = false
        stopCallStateListener()
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            channel = NotificationChannel(
                "example_service",
                "Example Service",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )
            channel.lightColor = NotificationCompat.COLOR_DEFAULT
            channel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
            manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
        createNotification()
    }

    private fun createNotification() {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        //val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

        builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "example_service")
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Hukuk Birimi")
            .setContentText("Kullanıcı girişi gerçekleşti")
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
           // .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Devam Et", pendingIntent)
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun startCallStateListener() {
        telephonyManager = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
        telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE)
    }

    private fun stopCallStateListener() {
        telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE)
    }

    private fun getCollectionNameFromSharedPreferences(): String? {
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("AppPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        return sharedPreferences.getString("CollectionName", null)
    }

    private val callStateListener = object : PhoneStateListener() {
    var wasRinging = false // Gelen arama için bayrak

    override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int, phoneNumber: String?) {
        val collectionName = getCollectionNameFromSharedPreferences() ?: return

        when (state) {
            TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING -> {
                // Gelen arama başladı
                wasRinging = true
                phoneNumber?.let { 
                    addCallStatusToNewCollection(it, "Gelen Arama: Çalıyor", collectionName, false,0)
                    addCallStatusToCallRegister(it,"Gelen Arama: Çalıyor",0,false)
                }
            }
            TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK -> {
                callStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                phoneNumber?.let {
                    if (!wasRinging) {
                        // Giden arama
                        addCallStatusToCallRegister(it,"Giden Arama: Cevaplandı",0,true)
                        //updateCallStatusInCallRegister(it, "Giden Arama: Cevaplandı",0,true)
                        updateCallStatus(it, "Giden Arama: Cevaplandı", collectionName, 0, true)
                    } else {
                        // Gelen arama cevaplandı
                        updateCallStatusInCallRegister("Gelen Arama: Cevaplandı",0,false)
                        updateCallStatus(it, "Gelen Arama: Cevaplandı", collectionName, 0, false)
                    }
                }
            }
            TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE -> {
                if (callStartTime != 0L) {
                    callEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    val callDuration = (callEndTime - callStartTime) / 1000
                    phoneNumber?.let {
                        updateCallStatus(it, "Arama Bitti", collectionName, callDuration, !wasRinging)
                        updateCallStatusInCallRegister("Arama Bitti",callDuration, !wasRinging)
                    }
                    callStartTime = 0
                    wasRinging = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Mainactivity,My makePhoneCall function,permisson

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "example_service"
    private val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    private val REQUEST_PERMISSION_CALL_PHONE = 1
    private val REQUEST_PERMISSION_READ_PHONE_STATE = 2
    private val REQUEST_PERMISSION_READ_CALL_LOG = 3


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)


       startExampleService("name","call")


        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            requestPermissions(
                arrayOf(
                    Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG
                ),
                REQUEST_PERMISSION_CALL_PHONE
            )
        }

    }


fun startExampleService(username: String, password: String) {
    val intent = Intent(this, ExampleService::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("username", username)
    intent.putExtra("password", password)
    startService(intent)
}


private fun listenForChanges(collectionName: String) {
    db.collection(collectionName).addSnapshotListener { snapshots, e ->
        if (e != null) {
            Log.w("Firebase", "Listen failed.", e)
            return@addSnapshotListener
        }

        snapshots?.documents?.forEach { document ->
            val directcall = document.getBoolean("directcall") ?: false
            val phonenumber = document.getString("phonenumber")

            if (directcall && phonenumber != null && isUserLoggedIn) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    makePhoneCall(phonenumber, collectionName)
                    updateDirectCallStatus(document.id, collectionName)
                } else {
                    requestPermissions(
                        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE),
                        REQUEST_PERMISSION_CALL_PHONE
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


private fun makePhoneCall(phoneNumber: String, collectionName: String) {
    if (collectionName.isNotEmpty()) {
        val dial = "tel:$phoneNumber"
        startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(dial)))
    } else {
      //
    }
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_PHONE_CALL" />


    <application
        android:label="ARAMA"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <service
            android:name=".ExampleService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" 
            android:foregroundServiceType="location|phoneCall"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```